# Cash to Change in Java

Tags: java

I am new to Java and was trying to write code that would tell you how much change you would receive for a given amount of money (in minimum number of coins). For example **$0.31** would give **1 quarters, 0 dimes, 1 nickels, 1 pennies**.

I got to a point where my code seemed to work. However, while most values work, specifically any multiple of 0.41 doesn't work (ex. 0.41, 0.82 ...). For example **$0.41** results in **1 quarters,
1 dimes, 1 nickels, 0 pennies**, which only adds up to $0.40.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Cash {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner_obj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Amount: $");
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(scanner_obj.nextLine());
        double[] change = calc_Change(amount);

        System.out.println(change[0] + " Quarters");
        System.out.println(change[1] + " Dimes");
        System.out.println(change[2] + " Nickels");
        System.out.println(change[3] + " Pennies");

        System.out.println(check_Change(amount, change));
    }

    public static double[] calc_Change(double amount){
        double[] change = {0, 0, 0, 0};

        while (amount >= 0.25){amount -= 0.25; change[0] += 1;}
        while (amount >= 0.10){amount -= 0.10; change[1] += 1;}
        while (amount >= 0.05){amount -= 0.05; change[2] += 1;}
        while (amount >= 0.01){amount -= 0.01; change[3] += 1;}

        return change;
    }

    public static boolean check_Change(double amount, double[] change){
        double total = change[0]*0.25 + change[1]*0.10 + change[2]*0.05 + change[3]*0.01;
        System.out.println(amount + " vs " + total);

        return (amount == total);
    }
}
```

I was using the check_Change function to check my results.

I don't know why this doesn't work and why it is only certain numbers.

Comment: First off, don't use double for currency. You could multiply by 100 and use cents instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are subtracting from a double - the internal representation is not exact - running your code and printing out the amount every time you subtract yields the following:

```
0.41
0.15999999999999998
0.05999999999999997
0.009999999999999967
```

As you can see the binary representation of the double is not exact...

try convert to an int (i.e. multiply by 100) then do the calculations

```
public class CashMain {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner_obj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Amount: $");
        double amount = Double.parseDouble(scanner_obj.nextLine());
        System.out.println(amount);
        int numCents = (int) (amount*100);
        System.out.println(numCents);
        
        int[] change = calc_Change(numCents);

        System.out.println(change[0] + " Quarters");
        System.out.println(change[1] + " Dimes");
        System.out.println(change[2] + " Nickels");
        System.out.println(change[3] + " Pennies");

        System.out.println(check_Change(numCents, change));
    }

    public static int[] calc_Change(int amount){
        int[] change = {0, 0, 0, 0};

        while (amount >= 25){
            amount -= 25; 
            change[0] += 1;
        }
        while (amount >= 10){
            amount -= 10; 
            change[1] += 1;
        }
        while (amount >= 5){
            amount -= 5; 
            change[2] += 1;
        }
        while (amount >= 1){
            amount -= 1; 
            change[3] += 1;
        }

        return change;
    }

    public static boolean check_Change(int amount, int[] change){
        int total = change[0]*25 + change[1]*10 + change[2]*5 + change[3]*1;
        System.out.println(amount + " vs " + total);

        return (amount == total);
    }
}
```

output

```
Enter Amount: $0.41
0.41
41
1 Quarters
1 Dimes
1 Nickels
1 Pennies
41 vs 41
true
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use BigDecimal for precision in your arithmetic operations.

```
public class Cash {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scanner_obj = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.print("Enter Amount: $");
        BigDecimal amount = new BigDecimal(scanner_obj.nextLine());
        double[] change = calc_Change(amount);

        System.out.println(change[0] + " Quarters");
        System.out.println(change[1] + " Dimes");
        System.out.println(change[2] + " Nickels");
        System.out.println(change[3] + " Pennies");

        System.out.println(check_Change(amount, change));
    }

    public static double[] calc_Change(BigDecimal amount){
        double[] change = {0, 0, 0, 0};

        while (amount.doubleValue() >= 0.25){
            amount = amount.subtract(new BigDecimal("0.25")); change[0]+=1;
        }
        while (amount.doubleValue() >= 0.10){
            amount = amount.subtract(new BigDecimal("0.10")); change[1] += 1;
        }
        while (amount.doubleValue() >= 0.05){
            amount = amount.subtract(new BigDecimal("0.05")); change[2] += 1;
        }
        while (amount.doubleValue() >= 0.01){
            amount = amount.subtract(new BigDecimal("0.01")); change[3] += 1;
        }

        return change;
    }

    public static boolean check_Change(BigDecimal amount, double[] change){
        double v1 = change[0] * 0.25;
        double v2 = change[1] * 0.10;
        double v3 = change[2] * 0.05;
        double v4 = change[3] * 0.01;
        double total = v1 + v2 + v3 + v4;
        System.out.println(amount + " vs " + total);

        return (amount.doubleValue() == total);
    }
}
```